# How can I pass the connectionstring from my selected publish-profile into the configuration of my Startup.cs-File?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

We have two different connectionstrings in the file **appsettings.json**. `DevConnection` is the database for our test system. `ProdConnection` is the database for our productive system:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "server=TestServer;Database=MyDatabase;user id=sql-User;Password=***;",
    "ProdConnection": "server=ProdServer;Database=MyDatabase;user id=sql-User;Password=***;"
  },
[...]
}
```

We have also two publishing profiles for `test-server` and `productive-server`. One for the testsystem. One for the productive system. We want to apply the connectionstrings `DevConnection`/`ProdConnection` for the publishing profiles `test-server` and `productive-server`:

[image]

How can I pass the connectionstring from my selected publish-profile into the configuration of my **Startup.cs**-File?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
    services.AddDbContext<KundenDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("?")));
}
```

Comment: Does [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) provide any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the structure of appsettings.json:

[image]

You can add different connction according to different environments.
You can add this to appsettings.Production.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Connection": "server=ProdServer;Database=MyDatabase;user id=sql-User;Password=***;"
  },
```

add this to appsettings.Development.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Connection": "server=TestServer;Database=MyDatabase;user id=sql-User;Password=***;",
  },
```

startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
    services.AddDbContext<KundenDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection")));
}
```